# how many alterations will be required for 60 shirts

Tags: combinatorics

If every 2 out of 3 ready made shirts need alterations in the sleeves, and every 4 out of 5 need it in the body, how many alterations will be required for 60 shirts?

The way I tried to solve it was as follows:

Total number of alterations = $60 * (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{2}{3} * \frac{4}{5}) = 120$

Comment: It will depend on whether a shirt requiring alterations in sleeves and body is to be counted as one alteration or two.

Comment: @trueblueanil I think that will be counted as one

Comment: In that case, assuming that defects in sleeves and body are independent events, you are overcounting, and the answer should be $60 * (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{5} -\frac{2}{3} * \frac{4}{5}) $

Comment: You might think of it as a probability problem.  What is the probability that a shirt will require alteration in the sleeve *or* body?  And then what is the expected number of alterations?

Comment: @trueblueanil why do we need to subtract $\frac{2}{3} * \frac{4}{5}$

Comment: @awkward in this case the answer is 88 but according to the answer on Jobzilla website, the answer is 133, maybe the answer there is written wrong!

Comment: @MoazNasem To answer your question, we subtract 2/3*4/5 because we are counting those shirts twice, once for needing alteration in the sleeves and once for the alteration in the body. Subtracting once brings it back to being counted once. You may also want to look into the principle of inclusion and exclusion, which gives a more general solution.